# Capturar e diminuir valores de múltiplas divs e inputs

Tags: php, xpath

Eu consegui com a ajuda do [@QMechanic73](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6454/qmechanic73/) 
, fazer um *parser* em um site remoto, e capturar os valores entre as tags `span` que está dentro de várias `div` com seu determinado `id`, e os `span` com suas `class` e valores entre suas *tags*, tive que capturar e diminuir os valores originais em *-20%*, o código ficou exatamente assim:

```php
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_contents('https://pt.sportingbet.com/services/InPlayApp.mvc/GetInPlaySports?CurrentOddsFormat=', false, $context);
$DOM =  new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);

$prices = $xpath->query('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "priceText ")]');
$percent = 20.0 / 100.0; // 20%

foreach($prices as $price){
    $value = $price->nodeValue;
    $floatValue = floatval($value);
    $finalValue = $floatValue - ($percent * $floatValue);
    $price->nodeValue = $finalValue; // Salva o valor final com desconto de 20%
}
echo $DOM->saveHTML();
```

Ok, tudo funcionou bonitinho e de acordo com o que eu queria, mas depois eu vi que para o site recuperar essas informações eu preciso alterar mais do que os valores das `span`, preciso alterar os valores entre 2 campos `input`.

### HTML

```all
<div id="isOffered">      
    <a class="price  " href="javascript:;">
        <span class="priceText wide  UK">1/4</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  EU">1.25</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  US">-400</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  CH">1.25</span>
        <span class="priceChangeArrow" ></span>
        <input type="hidden" class="betCode" value="0]SK@84899932@323698807@NB*1~4*0*-1*0*0"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="decValue" value="1.25"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="originalBetCode" value="0]SK@84899932@323698807@NB*1~4*0*-1*0*0"/>
     </a>
</div>

<div class="market-item ">
    <div class="outright-label">Empate</div>
    <div class="outright-odds" title="Vencedor do Encontro">
    <div id="s_323698809" class="odds draw">   <div id="isNotOffered" class="hide">    
    <span class="price priceReadonly"></span>
</div>

<div id="isOffered">      
    <a class="price  " href="javascript:;">
        <span class="priceText wide  UK">3/1</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  EU">4.00</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  US">+300</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  CH">4.00</span>
        <span class="priceChangeArrow" ></span>
        <input type="hidden" class="betCode" value="0]SK@84899932@323698809@NB*3~1*0*-1*0*0"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="decValue" value="4.00"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="originalBetCode" value="0]SK@84899932@323698809@NB*3~1*0*-1*0*0"/>
    </a>
 </div></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Os campos que precisam de alteração são as `input` de `class= "decValue"` e `class= "betCode"` e se possível também a `class = "originalBetCode"`. O campo `input` com a `class` de `decValue` é mais simples, pois só precisamos diminuir em *20%* como nos campos `span`.

Mas quero voltar a atenção para o `input` com a `class = "BetCode"` e `originalBetCode`, pois precisarei alterar apenas os 2 números que estão entre `~`, e pra fazer isso eu precisarei seguir um `esquema` de cálculos que será assim:

Eu terei que capturar cada valor obtido nas `span priceText EU` já com a diminuição de *20%*, ou seja, se no site remoto o valor é `2.30`, o script do QMechanic73 irá diminuir em *20%* como desejado, então nosso valor ficará `2.30 - 20% = 1.84`, agora eu terei que pegar este *1.84* e diminuir *1* dele, (lá na frente explico porque), depois de diminuir este *1.84* por *1*, terei que pegar o resultado *0.84* e multiplicar por um valor *fixo*, que pode ser qualquer número, irei usar então o *5*, então *0.84 * 5* será igual a *4.2*, o que iremos fazer com este valor? simples! mandar ele pra substituir aqueles dois números no campo `BetCode`, só que da seguinte maneira; se por exemplo o nosso código estiver `value="0]SK@84899932@323698807@NB*1~4*0*-1*0*0"` iremos substituir o *1* que está depois do `@NB` pelo nosso valor multiplicado, que no caso é *4.2*, e o *4* que está depois do `~` é o divisor, então se nosso *multiplicador* for sempre *5*, nosso `divisor` também será, então iremos substituir o *1~4* por *4.2~5*, por quê assim iremos obter o resultado de *0.84*, então este script irá automaticamente somar *+1* em todos os resultados obtido por nossa divisão!

Se quisermos que o valor seja *3.2*, teremos que diminuir isso por *1*, e multiplicar o *2.2* por *5* por exemplo, e o resultado obtido *11* ser enviado ao `BetCode` da seguinte maneira:
*11~5*, *11* é o valor total, dividido por *5* que é nosso multiplicador *+1* automático do script original.

Então quero fazer isso adaptando o script do @QMechanic73, desculpa pela longa explicação, mas queria uma ajuda de como fazer isso! alguém tem ideia?
e se possível, um limitador, pra que se um valor diminuído em *20%* dê apenas centavos, ele retorne o valor *1.00* por exemplo; o valor original é *1.20*, se eu diminuir em *20%* ele ficaria *0.96*, o que daria errado, então o PHP iria analisar os números que viesse abaixo de *1.00* e elevar ele pra *1.00*.

Sei que é extenso, é chato, mas preciso mesmo da ajuda de vocês.
Obrigado desde já pessoal

Comment: Isso é só um aviso gerado pelo PHP. O código atual não funciona?

Comment: Não funciona! funciona apenas quando tem uma única div, já quando são muitas ele gera esse aviso e não me retorna nada.

Comment: @CassianoJosé Fiz algo parcial aqui mas tenho uma dúvida: qual o valor que você quer pegar inicialmente? o valor de `decValue` ou o valor de `priceText wide  UK`? na pergunta você menciona que quer diminuir em 20% o valor de **ambas**, qual das duas entra na operação de calculo?

Comment: @QMechanic73, é do campo `priceText wide  EU`, eu errei, mas editei agora.
Mas vale ressaltar que o campo `priceText wide  UK` sempre contém o mesmo valor que tem na `betcode`, tipo: se na `div` tiver `1/4` no `priceText UK`, isso quer dizer que no `betcode` terá `1~4`, inclusive estava tentando usar o valor obtido na `UK`, substituir a barra por `~`, e fazer a procura no betcode, mas não consegui muita coisa. tem funções PHP que ainda não estudei, aí dificulta :(. mas espero que me ajudar a fazer rs =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: ID isOffered already defined in Entity
```

Essa mensagem de aviso é lançada quando o HTML a ser analisado contem dois ou mais identificadores iguais, nesse caso o `isOffered`, um *ID* é um identificador único, como citado [nessa página](http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html) do [W3](http://www.w3.org/), cada vez que esse atributo for utilizado em um documento ele deve ter um valor diferente.

Para ignorar esse tipo de erro pode-se usar a função [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php), ao utilizá-la com o parâmetro *true* você vai desabilitar os erros da [libxml](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.libxml.php) e habilitará o manuseamento do erro, por exemplo:

```php
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = DOMDocument::load('file.xml');

if (!$doc){
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        // Tratar os erros manualmente aqui
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

A função [`libxml_clear_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.libxml-clear-errors.php) é utilizada para limpar o [buffer](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) de erros da [libxml](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.libxml.php). Uma outra **provável** alternativa é utilizar o [operador de controle de erro](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), o sinal `@`, quando ele precede uma expressão, qualquer mensagem de erro que possa ser gerada por aquela expressão será ignorada.

O problema parcial já foi tratado, agora a outra parte do problema, para alterar o valor dos elementos [*input*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) das classes *betCode*, *originalBetCode* e *DecValue*, primeiramente teremos que obter os valores dessas classes e depois substituir por um valor que desejarmos.

```
$decValues = $xpath->query('//input[@class="decValue"]/@value');
$betCodes  = $xpath->query('//input[@class="betCode"]/@value');
$originalBetCodes = $xpath->query('//input[@class="originalBetCode"]/@value');
```

Na variável `decValues` estará os valores do campo *value* da classe *decValue*, na variável `betCodes` estará armazenado os valores do campo `value` da classe *betCode* e mesmo acontece com a variável *originalBetCodes*.

Caso a [`query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domxpath.query.php) não retorne nenhum resultado o seu valor de retorno será *false*, um [valor booleano](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booliano) e consequente será lançada uma mensagem de erro ao tentar percorrê-la com o [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php#control-structures.foreach).

Para tratar esse **possível** erro, utilize a função [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-array.php) antes de tentar utilizar um [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), como tenho certeza que a [`query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domxpath.query.php) vai retornar resultados não irei usá-la, mas fica uma informação aqui.

Daqui em diante basta você percorrer essas variáveis e fazer os cálculos necessários, a função [`query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domxpath.query.php) do [`DomXpath`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php) retorna um objeto [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php) que por sua vez implementa a interface [`Transversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), para convertê-la  num objeto [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) foi usado a função [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.iterator-to-array.php) e posteriormente usada em um [array multidimensional](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp). Logo abaixo tem um exemplo, com base naquilo que consegui entender, *comentei alguns trechos*.

```php
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('GetInPlaySports.html'); //  
$outputFile = "GetInPlaySports2.html"; // Arquivo onde será salvo o HTML modificado
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$DOM =  new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);

$decValues = $xpath->query('//input[@class="decValue"]/@value'); // Obtem os campos "value" da classe "decValue"
$betCodes  = $xpath->query('//input[@class="betCode"]/@value');  // Obtem os campos "value" da classe "betCode"
$originalBetCodes = $xpath->query('//input[@class="originalBetCode"]/@value');  // Obtem os campos "value" da classe "originalBetCode"
// Uma array de arrays
$arrValues = array_map(null, iterator_to_array($decValues), 
                             iterator_to_array($betCodes),
                             iterator_to_array($originalBetCodes));

$percent = 20.0 / 100.0; 
$mult = 5;

foreach($arrValues as $value){
    $floatValue = floatval($value[0]->nodeValue); // Pega o valor de "decValue"
    $discountValue = $floatValue - ($percent * $floatValue);
    $expr = (((($discountValue < 1)? round($discountValue): $discountValue) - 1) * $mult);
    $finalValue = "*". $expr. "~". $mult. "*";
    
    $betValue = $value[1]->nodeValue; // Obtem o valor de "betCode"
    $repl = preg_replace('/\*(\d+)~(\d+)\*/', $finalValue, $betValue);
    $value[1]->nodeValue = $repl; // Atualiza o campo "value" da classe "betCode"
    $value[2]->nodeValue = $repl; // Atualiza o campo "value" da classe "originalBetCode"
}

libxml_clear_errors();
file_put_contents($outputFile, $DOM->saveHTML());
echo "Done!";
```

Esse exemplo vai receber uma página com [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) e salvar o arquivo com as modificações realizadas com o [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php).

Também há um *limitador*, tendo como exemplo o valor *1.20* quando subtraído há uma condição que vai verificar se o resultado é menor que *1*, no caso será *0.96*, através de uma condição arredondamos esse valor para *1.00* com o uso da função [`round`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php).

[**Aqui**](https://ideone.com/hMy2C6) há um exemplo adaptado do código acima.

Comment: @CassianoJosé Não conhecia. Pelo que li [aqui](http://sembugs.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/o-que-e-headless-browser.html) isso parece ser uma boa solução para isso que você procura!

Comment: QMechanic73, mas ele é um navegador a parte?
não consegui entender direito.
Deixar pra procurar mais sobre o assunto de manhã.

Answer (score 0):

Não funciona porque esse HTML é inválido: "Não podem existir duas entidades com o mesmo id."

De qualquer forma, se o seu problema são os erros do PHP, esperimente adicionar isto no início do seu código:

`libxml_use_internal_errors(true) AND libxml_clear_errors();`